# Webpack4: <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> not picking up the value

Tags: webpack, title

Based on this tuorial:
[using html-webpack-plugin to generate index.html](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/index-html-using-html-webpack-plugin-85eabdb73474)
If you add a **title** option to html-webpack-plugin options like this:

```
new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.html',
  filename: './index.html',
  title: 'My App',
}),
```

And add the following snippet to your HTML template

```
<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```

It should pick up the title value from the plugin settings and show it inside the title tag.

But it seems that `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>` doesn't pick up the value! Could it be, that this feature is deprecated in Webpack 4?

Comment: Can any one confirm this?

Answer (score 7):

I removed html-loader from webpack.config.js.
   And then, it works like a charm
Regards

Answer (score 2):

@user1941537

install the following dependencies:

```
npm install -D --safe-dev ejs-loader extract-loader
```

And add the rule for .html files as follows,

```
rules:[{
        test: /\.html$/,
        use:  ['ejs-loader', 'extract-loader', 'html-loader'] 
}]
```

Comment: ejs loader is unnecessary. The template in question only has a .html file.